# what is the best syntax to built any jquery plugins?

Tags: jquery

I want to build my own plugins in Jquery.

So i want to know

- best syntax and way of coding(way of using variables,options,functions,methods etc...).
- I want to build plugins like menus+dropdowns,image gallery etc...
- what are the issues i should keep in mind while building Jquery plugins.

I want to build almost every plugin in jquery. So kindly please guide me to create awesome plugins in Jquery

-Thank you to all stackoverians and jquerians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not google it.

- [Developing a jQuery Plugin](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery_plugin/)
- [jQuery Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)
- [Building Your First jQuery Plugin](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html)
- [Learn How to Create a jQuery Plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/learn-how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/)

If you are going to develop jQuery plugins for practice then its OK otherwise existing jQuery plugins are easy to use and time saving.

- [List of Useful jQuery Plugins](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/list-of-useful-jquery-plugins)
- [240 plugins jquery](http://www.sastgroup.com/jquery/240-plugins-jquery)
- http://plugins.jquery.com/